# Conversation through skype

Tags: sentence-choice

We started the conversation throught skype and 1my companinon didn't turn on his web-cam. How to ask the following:

> Will we talk without seeing through web cams?

in a more natural non-formal way?

Comment: In a more natural, non formal way would be: Are we going to talk without using our web cams? OR (but I would never use that, it doesn't make sense really) Will we talk without having our web cams on. I suggest using present continuous here (starting with present continous). Will just doesn't fit here...

Comment: Can you clarify who you are talking to? If you are talking to a friend you can make a joke but if you're talking to a client or your boss, you will need to be more respectful.

Comment: The most common way to say this is actually: "Your video isn't working."

Answer (score 2):

Possible combinations that I'd definitely use in a non formal conversation:

- Are we going to talk without using our web cams?
- Are we going to talk without having our web cams on?

The point is when starting such conversation, try to use present continuous as much as possible, especially at the starting point of the conversation.

```
Will we talk without seeing through web cams?
```

The sentence that you are using is utterly unnatural. However, if you really want to stick to it then surplus it:

Will we talk without seeing each other through web cams?

Answer (score 1):

As I said in my comment, what you say **really** depends on who you're talking to.

You have a couple of different options but my preference is to "blame the technology".

You can say something like:

> Hold on a minute [sir/ma'am/Mr. Jones/Sally], I'm not getting video... do you want to do this voice-only or should we try to get video running?

This can work for just about anyone. It lets you say that you're not receiving video and you're making an assumption that it's a technical issue but giving them the chance to say that they are OK with a voice-only conversation. If they *do* want video, you can try to figure out what's wrong.

Comment: Interesting, but couldn't you explain the phrase get video running. To me, it looks a bit confused. What in general does mean get sth running, if it can use it in general...

Comment: @DmitryBundin "running" means "working". [Definitions 6 and 7](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/run_1).

Answer (score 0):

Are we not going to use the video?

or

Are you going to turn your video on?

Comment: Are you going to turn your video on? could be misunderstood as being a demand.  I might ask "Do you want to use video, or just audio?"

Comment: Are we not going to use the video?????

Comment: I think in any informal case, the second wouldn't be inappropriate as demanding.

Answer (score 0):

As you said , the person on the other side is your companion and you want to use a non-formal way, thus I would have used some thing like this

> Can we talk with our skype video turned on?